# How can I add a fixed footer in my flatlist/ ModalFlatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native

is there a way to add a fixed footer with flatlist ?

I use this libary:

```
[https://github.com/jeremybarbet/react-native-modalize][1]
```

I use a modal libary and I have this code:

```
    <Modalize
      ref={ref}
      modalStyle={{ flex: 1, padding: 8 }}
      flatListProps={{
        data: newArr(),
        style: {
          padding: 0,
          flex: 1
        },
        renderItem: renderItem,
        ListEmptyComponent: ShowTextWhenArrayIsEmpty,
        ListHeaderComponent: <View style={s.header}>
        <Text style={s.headerTitle}>Nachricht verschicken</Text>
        <Input value={searchText} onChangeText={handleChangeText} placeholder='Person suchen...' style={s.textInput} />
      </View>,
        keyExtractor: (item, i) => i.toString(),
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator: false,
        stickyHeaderIndices: [0],
        scrollEventThrottle: 16,
        maxToRenderPerBatch: 2,
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps: 'handled',
        initialNumToRender: 4,
        updateCellsBatchingPeriod: 200,
        getItemLayout: (data, index) => ({ length: 40, offset: 40 * index, index }),
        contentContainerStyle: {
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center'
        }
      }}
    />
```

is there a way to do this or not ? I need your help please

Answer (score 0):

[As you can see in the docs:](https://jeremybarbet.github.io/react-native-modalize/#/PROPS?id=flatlistprops)

> flatListProps:    An object to pass any of the react-native FlatList's
> props. Using this props will replace the default ScrollView with the
> FlatList component.

That means you can use react native's flatlist props as they are. So, you can use [ListFooterComponent](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listfootercomponent) just like you used ListHeaderComponent and ListEmptyComponent.

Comment: I asked for fixed footer, not a normal footer